# What is the best escape character strategy for Python/MySQL combo?

Tags: python, mysql, escaping

This is my query.

```
cursor2.execute("update myTable set `"+ str(row[1]) +"` = \"'" + str(row[3]) +"'\" where ID = '"+str(row[0])+"'")
```

It is failing when row values have double quotes "some value". How do I escape all special characters?

Comment: The best escape strategy for Python + MySQL are prepared queries.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @zneak: prapare an extended insert with 1k rows.

Comment: @Mchl: I'd prepare an insert statement and run it 1k times. What's the problem?

Comment: @zneak: 300% difference in performane according to my testing (InnoDB, multiple inserts within transaction, MySQL 5.1.x). It was a lousy benchmark, but shows that it's something you should pay attention to.

Comment: To be clear: I don't deny usefulness of prepared statements. Just say they can be unwieldy at some cases.

Comment: I don't think an extended insert with 1k tuples is "wieldy" no matter what.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import MySQLdb
column = str(MySQLdb.escape_string(row[1]))
query = "update myTable set %(column)s = %%s where ID = %%s" % dict(column = column) 
cursor2.execute(query, [row[3], row[0]])
```

**Update**

Here is a brief commentary:

```
column = str(MySQLdb.escape_string(row[1]))
```

Always a good idea to escape anything that goes into a query. In this case we are dynamically adding a column name and hence it has to be escaped before the query is executed.

```
query = "update myTable set %(column)s = %%s where ID = %%s" % dict(column = column)
```

I am forming the query here. I am trying to achieve two things: (1) form a query with column name populated using the `column` variable declared in the previous line (2) add placeholders that will be filled in by actual parameters during query execution.

The snippet `dict(column = column)` is actually another way of creating the dictionary `{'column': column}`. This is made possible using the [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) constructor. I don't want to 
 fill in the other place holders just yet so I escape them using two percentage signs (`%%`).

```
cursor2.execute(query, [row[3], row[0]])
```

Finally execute the query. If you print query before executing you'll see the string `update myTable set column_name = %s where ID = %s`.

Comment: Could you please explain your approach? It worked brilliantly! I didn't understand the  dict(column = column) part..

Comment: Column escape is wrong here, columns are identifiers and needs ` characters around and doubled `` if there're some of theses inside (in the column name), not a quote escaping.

Comment: Agreeing with regilero, the code example above is vulnerable to a malicious `column` value.  It should be something like:

`column = "\`{0}\`".format(column.replace('\`', '\`\`'))`

I wound up here wondering if MySQLdb provided this service but it looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 7):

For values, you should use prepared queries to embed them. For the rows, I'm not too sure... it depends on your setting. You'll probably want to accept any character above the ASCII value 32 except an unescaped backtick. Don't think there's a specific function for this, though.

```
cursor2.execute("UPDATE myTable SET `" + str(row[1]) + "` = ? WHERE ID = ?", (row[3], row[1]))
```

Prepared queries have question marks where there should be variables, and you pass in a list or a tuple as a second argument to specify what they should be substituted with. The driver will take care of making the values safe. You can only put interrogation marks where values are expected, though; so you can't use them as column names.

Answer (score 7):

You should learn to use query parameters:

```
colname = str(row[1]).replace("`", "\\`")
sql = "update myTable set `%s` = :col1 WHERE ID = :id" % (colname)
cursor2.execute(sql, {"col1":str(row[3]), "id":str(row[0])})
```

Comment: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':col1 WHERE ID = :id' at line 1")  Any pointers? Thank you..

Comment: Perhaps the named parameters are for Oracle only.  Try using `?` positional parameters instead as in the answer from @zneak.

Answer (score 2):

When you using [Oracle MySql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html) you can escape special characters in a follow way:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import conversion

query = "SELECT id, code, name, description FROM data WHERE code='{:s}'"

escaped_text = conversion.MySQLConverter().escape(unescaped_text)

cursor.execute(query.format(escaped_text))
```

Comment: This seemingly doesn't work as expected: `conversion.MySQLConverter().escape('blah; truncate other;')` => `'blah; truncate other;'`.